# Line-Wrapping on Long Words

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app

There's a bug in the current version of the iOS SE app (0.1.61). Long words (e.g. method names) are truncated instead of wrapped (or IMO even better the view should become scrollable).
The complete method name in the [example beneath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21743913/what-is-a-good-way-to-determine-significant-movement-with-the-ios-accelerometer/21959133%2321959133) is `- (void)allowDeferredLocationUpdatesUntilTraveled:`

[image: Bug]

Comment: And I've just found out that the `Submit` button in the preview VC does not work.

Comment: And just got the update notification for .63 where the issue still exists.

Comment: the submit button issue should be fixed in the latest version (0.1.64)

Comment: Taking a look at this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue should be fixed in version **0.1.65**