# Numbered lists and code block

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app

Here is a code block:

```
HappyCodeHappyCodeHappyCodeHappyCodeHappyCodeHappyCodeHappyCodeHappyCodeHappyCodeHappyCodeHappyCodeHappyCodeHappyCodeHappyCodeHappyCodeHappyCodeHappyCodeHappyCodeHappyCodeHappyCodeHappyCodeHappyCodeHappyCodeHappyCodeHappyCodeHappyCodeHappyCodeHappyCodeHappyCodeHappyCodeHappyCodeHappyCode
```

Now here is a code block after a numbered list (with 8 spaces for indentation:

1. Test

   ```
   HappyCodeHappyCodeHappyCodeHappyCodeHappyCodeHappyCodeHappyCodeHappyCodeHappyCodeHappyCodeHappyCodeHappyCodeHappyCodeHappyCodeHappyCodeHappyCodeHappyCodeHappyCodeHappyCodeHappyCodeHappyCodeHappyCodeHappyCodeHappyCodeHappyCodeHappyCodeHappyCodeHappyCodeHappyCodeHappyCodeHappyCodeHappyCode
   ```

Notice how if you look at this question on the mobile app (for iOS), the first code block is all one line with scrolling, but the second breaks so it doesn't scroll:

[image]

Comment: Which behavior do you want it to stick with?

Comment: @NathanTuggy Its not up to me, I'm just making the SE team aware of this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will be fixed in 1.4.4.3.

This bug was introduced with the fix to [Line-Wrapping on Long Words](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230790/line-wrapping-on-long-words) when the following CSS was added to the app:

```
li code {
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

This made long *inline* code like `HappyCodeHappyCodeHappyCodeHappyCodeHappyCodeHappyCodeHappyCodeHappyCodeHappyCodeHappyCodeHappyCodeHappyCodeHappyCodeHappyCodeHappyCodeHappyCodeHappyCodeHappyCodeHappyCodeHappyCodeHappyCodeHappyCodeHappyCodeHappyCodeHappyCodeHappyCodeHappyCodeHappyCodeHappyCodeHappyCodeHappyCodeHappyCode` wrap correctly but broke code blocks.

I'm adding a rule to reset code blocks back to their normal behavior:

```
li pre code {
    word-wrap: normal;
}
```