# URLs are cut off in bulleted lists

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app

See [this answer](https://chess.stackexchange.com/a/16449) for an example.  I can't horizontally scroll the post to see the full URL in a bulleted list.

> [image: URL in list]

- App Version: 1.6.3.5
- Device: iPhone 6
- OS Version: Version 10.2 (Build 14C92)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be fixed in 1.6.3.6.

[This was fixed almost 3 years ago for inline `code`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230790/line-wrapping-on-long-words) but either the site changed or we just missed it for everything else.

Comment: Sounds good, thanks for the quick reply Brian!